# Is it possible to customize the key of java stream groupingBy?

Tags: java

I'd like to grouping employees by surname, the code is simple with java Stream.

```
employees.stream().groupingBy(Emplyee::getSurname);
```

It will return the result with `HashMap` structure and the key is the surname. So can I customize the key's pattern, such like adding a prefix string that looks like below?

```
{
  "Surname=Smith":[...],
  "Surname=Jones":[...]
}
```

Comment: `...groupingBy(e -> String.format("Surname=%s", e.getSurname()));`? I wonder, however, why one would do this. This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to prefix the key?

Comment: Thank your answer and comment. That is because I just do not want to resemble the format of the result before push to the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(new Employee("a"), new Employee("a"), new Employee("b"));
    final String prefix = "Surname=";
    Map<String, List<Employee>> grouped = employees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(employee -> prefix + employee.getSurname()));
```

Comment: Posting code-only answer is discouraged. We should explain the problem(s) and how the presented solution solves it(them).

Comment: Thanks for advice. In most cases - yes, you are absolutely right, 
it's better to explain problem and presented solution. But I also think that in some cases (like that) clear and simple 
code could explain much better then any additional comments.

Comment: Thanks, thanks all of you. i did the same thing but i did not notice another trick which led failure.t

Answer (score 1):

groupBy signature takes java function
`groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier)`
so you can do any changes to the key

i.e.

```
.collect(Collectors.groupBy(myKey()));

private Function<Employee, String> myKey() {
    return employee -> "Surname=" + employee.getSurname();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But what confused me is  why the classification benchmark is still emmployee.getSurname() instead of "Surname=" + employee.getSurname().

Comment: I'm not really understand you question. probably you're asking something below.
you can add to your employee object the method
```public String getSurnameKey() {
return "Surname=" + this.surname;
}```
and just do groupBy by this one ```groupBy(Employee::getSurnameKey)```

Comment: Got it. That's great.